# how to change ringer mode to (Silent or Vibrate) mode in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am using ionic v1 and I need to change the ringer mode to silent automatically. Is this possible?

I have tried to find any topics that talk about this issue but did not find any

Comment: I didn't get your exact problem .What you tried till now? For Vibration there is a plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/vibration/

Comment: I am trying to change the phone into silent mode when I click on a button or something, I have checked this plugin before but it does not help in my case.

Comment: did you find an answer? There is a [how to](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-put-an-android-on-%E2%80%9Csilent%E2%80%9D-mode-for-a-specific-amount-of-time-programmatically) do that, but it is in Android native.. it's interesting how to do that with ionic/cordova ..